# Check return status of background process

Tags: shell, background

I need to copy several files to remote server.

```
for database in `mysql -Bse"show databases" | grep '^us' `
do

time scp $database.gz gs://tbl_name/ &

done
```

I use **&** to push the process in the background so that the script can continue processing the next file. The problem is that 1 out of 10 files are not being able to transfer due to network problem. But I can not check the return code and hence do not know which files have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for specific processes and get the status from that:

```
cmd &
pid=$!
cmd2 &
pid2=$!
wait $pid || echo cmd failed >&2
wait $pid2 || echo cmd2 failed >&2
```